# How to Copy to Clipboard text from <code> and <pre> tags using Jquery and JS?

Tags: html, jquery, css

According to [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select)

> The HTMLInputElement.select() method selects all the text in a  element or in an  element that includes a text field.

That means `.select()` does not work on the element other than `input` and `textarea`. In my case, I have some strings in `code` and `pre` that I would like user to click on copy button to copy the text inside but according to definition above that does not work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('code, pre').append('<span class="command-copy" ><i class="fa fa-clipboard" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>');

  $('code span.command-copy').click(function(e) {
    text = $(this).parent().select(); //.text();
    copiedText = $.trim(text);
    document.execCommand("copy");
  });


  $('pre span.command-copy').click(function(e) {
    text = $(this).parent().parent().select(); //.text();
    copiedText = $.trim(text);
    document.execCommand("copy");
  });
})
```

```css
code,
pre {
  position: relative;
}

code,
pre {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  color: #555755;
}

span.command-copy {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  opacity: .6;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #555755;
}

span.command-copy:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h4>
  <b>Steps to install pytest</b>
</h4>
<p>
  <b>Step 1: </b>Open the terminal and type in this command:

</p>
<code class="command-copy">
        pip install pytest 
</code>
<p>Or you can upgrade your existing:
  <p>

    <pre><span></span><span class="nv">pip</span> install --upgrade pytest
<span class="command-copy"><i class="fa fa-clipboard" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></pre>
```

Is any way I can work around this? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you can copy to clipboard your text on click event by adding some java-script to your existing code.

[.select()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select) will not work in your case because its ONLY selects the text but its does not copy it which in your case you need to click to copy and paste as well.

Few things added:

1. You need to create element in `body` and copy your text value into it
2. `document.execCommand('copy');` will that value from the input
3. Once it copied successfully it will delete the input value from DOM

Run snippet below to see it working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('code, pre').append('<span class="command-copy" ><i class="fa fa-clipboard" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>');

  $('code span.command-copy').click(function(e) {
    var text = $(this).parent().text().trim(); //.text();
    var copyHex = document.createElement('input');
    copyHex.value = text
    document.body.appendChild(copyHex);
    copyHex.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    console.log(copyHex.value)
    document.body.removeChild(copyHex);
  });


  $('pre span.command-copy').click(function(e) {
    var text = $(this).parent().text().trim();
    var copyHex = document.createElement('input');
    copyHex.value = text
    document.body.appendChild(copyHex);
    copyHex.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    console.log(copyHex.value)
    document.body.removeChild(copyHex);
  });
})
```

```css
code,
pre {
  position: relative;
}

code,
pre {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  color: #555755;
}

span.command-copy {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  opacity: .6;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #555755;
}

span.command-copy:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h4>
  <b>Steps to install pytest</b>
</h4>
<p>
  <b>Step 1: </b>Open the terminal and type in this command:

</p>
<code class="command-copy">
        pip install pytest 
</code>
<p>Or you can upgrade your existing:
  <p>

    <pre><span></span><span class="nv">pip</span> install --upgrade pytest
<span class="command-copy"><i class="fa fa-clipboard" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></pre>
```

Comment: thank you very much, it is very helpful answer and that works : )

Comment: @HouyNarun You are welcome. Glad to hear. Thanks :)

Comment: in case the text is multiple lines. How can I make them enter new line as a copied result? any way, thank you for your help.

Comment: @HouyNarun If the text is multiple line then it will still be selected - for example if four line it will become a paragraph. You can use the code for other input or multiple paragraph you want to copy on click.

Comment: I work around multiple lines by changing `var copyHex = document.createElement('input');` to `var copyHex = document.createElement('textarea');` so it preserves the new line as it before copy. Anyway thank you  :)